# "Home site" of 2015 election voters

Tags: discussion, election

A while back, [some folks on Math.SE were interested in knowing the "home site" of the voters in one of their moderator elections](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18842/). Here, "home site" means "the SE site on which the user has the most reputation". I surmise that there were fears that unwashed masses of programmers were invading their site and ruining their elections.

I wrote up [a query](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18965/) to answer their question. Here are the results of that same query for [our recent election](https://anime.stackexchange.com/election/1):

```
Count SiteName                  
----- ------------------------- 
64    StackExchange.Anime       
48    StackOverflow             
11    StackExchange.Gaming      
3     StackExchange.Puzzling    
3     StackExchange.Scifi       
2     StackExchange.Math        
2     StackExchange.Movies      
2     StackExchange.GameDev     
2     StackExchange.Codereview  
1     StackExchange.Drupal      
1     StackExchange.Blender     
1     StackExchange.Android     
1     StackExchange.German      
1     StackExchange.Philosophy  
1     StackExchange.Programmers
```

Lots of users from here and SO? Who woulda thunk it?

So, yeah. In case anybody cares.

Comment: Who is the second person from movies O-o