# "Home sites" of 2016 election voters

Tags: discussion, election

In the same vein as ["Home site" of 2015 election voters](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2593/), here are [the "home sites"](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/261422/home-site-of-election-voters?ElectionStartDate=2016-08-01&NextElectionStartDate=2016-10-01) of the voters in [our 2016 election](https://anime.stackexchange.com/election/2):

```
Count SiteName                   
----- -------------------------- 
61    StackExchange.Anime        
56    StackOverflow              
9     StackExchange.Gaming       
4     StackExchange.GameDev      
4     StackExchange.Math         
4     StackExchange.Scifi        
2     StackExchange.Codereview   
2     StackExchange.Ell          
2     StackExchange.Programmers  
2     StackExchange.Puzzling     
1     StackExchange.Android      
1     StackExchange.Apple        
1     StackExchange.Blender      
1     StackExchange.Chemistry    
1     StackExchange.Codegolf     
1     StackExchange.Drupal       
1     StackExchange.Electronics  
1     StackExchange.English      
1     StackExchange.German       
1     StackExchange.Japanese     
1     StackExchange.Lifehacks    
1     StackExchange.Mathoverflow 
1     StackExchange.Movies       
1     StackExchange.Physics      
1     StackExchange.Sharepoint   
1     StackExchange.Skeptics     
1     StackExchange.Space        
1     StackExchange.Startups     
1     StackExchange.Travel       
1     StackExchange.Ubuntu       
1     SuperUser
```

Again, there's nothing terribly surprising here, but someone might find this data interesting.

Comment: I'd like to ask how other small sites like ours compare with their own vs SO voter percentage, just out of curiosity

Comment: I also voted and my home site is movies.se, Is there some issue with this stats

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yes, there appears to be some kind of bug. The query I linked returns 28 rows, but when I remove the ORDER BY clause from the final SELECT, it returns 31 rows. One of the missing rows is a count of 1 for StackExchange.Movies, which I suppose is you. I do not know currently know why this is happening.

Comment: @AnkitSharma There was no bug; I'm just an idiot - I ran this query too soon after the election ended, meaning that some of the people who voted towards the end of the election (like you) earned their Constituent badges after the Sept 4 SEDE import. Another import happened an hour ago, which includes everybody who voted in the election, so the data I'm about to edit in should be correct for real.

Comment: @Hakase So, one of the issues with doing that is that we are forced to determine a user's home site based on their reputation _at the time the query is run_, rather than their reputation at the time they voted (because SEDE doesn't have a reputation history table, and re-computing reputation snapshots from votes and stuff takes long enough that SEDE will kill the query). This is why I ran the queries for us quite soon after the election ended. With that caveat in mind, I can run this for some other sites (not now but in the near future) and report my findings since you're interested.

Comment: Ok I understand these limitations and yes I'm still interested to learn about how many residents and non-residents vote on average and how we compare.